# How to convert the below struct in c to python?

Tags: python, network-programming, netlink

How can I convert the ieee80211_hdr(below) to python struct which can decode the bytearray and store the variables?

Thanks

```
struct ieee80211_hdr {
    unsigned char frame_control[2];
    unsigned char duration_id[2];
    unsigned char addr1[6];
    unsigned char addr2[6];
    unsigned char addr3[6];
    unsigned char seq_ctrl[2];
    unsigned char addr4[6];
```

};

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It explicitly states "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**- copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing the information.I modified the question.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Please use StackOverflow's features to embed code as text, not using images.

How you are using `struct` translates to a `class` as follows:

```py
class ieee80211_hrd:
    def __init__(self, frame_control, duration_id, addr1, addr2, addr3, seq_ctrl, addr4):
        self.frame_control = frame_control
        self.duration_id = duration_id
        self.addr1 = addr1
        self.addr2 = addr2
        self.addr3 = addr3
        self.seq_ctrl = seq_ctrl
        self.addr4 = addr4
```

This creates an object you can use like this

```py
thing = ieee80211_hrd("ab", "cd", "efghij", "klmnop", "qrstuv", "wx", "yz1234")
print(thing.addr3)
# and so on, where `thing.addr3`, etc. are persistent variables in the class instance `thing`
```

Comment: Hi,Consider if line like "struct ieee80211_hdr *hdr = (struct ieee80211_hdr *)data;".  If the data is bytearray how can a class ,split it into variables? For example I'm getting incoming data which is in bytearray format. if I create an object of class ieee80211_hdr() = data; where data=b'\x42\x00\x00.....' . ieee80211_hdr.addr1=42:00:..."  does it works like this? I dont think so. But thanks for the reply..

Comment: You could do something like `instance = ieee80211_hdr(data[0:2], data[2:4], data[4:8], ...)`

Comment: ������ ������ ������ ������ ������ ������ Hi I tried slicing the bytearray as per the ieee80211_hdr format but I see above info when I print hdr.addr1 ,instead of the mac addr which is 42:00::..

Comment: You copy-paste did not work, but it sounds like you may want to ignore the ":" characters, which may just be adjusting the indices you slice. (Like [0:2] [3:5] [6:10] instead.)

Comment: @HunterMorris Fields in IEEE 802.11 are not strings, but packed binary data.

Comment: @Yuri Ginsburg Any idea how to unpack the received bytearray data from the kernel into ieee80211_hdr struct ? I need to know the addr1 field of it.

Comment: `bytes` and `bytearray`s can still be indexed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a struct class in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

> This module performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python bytes objects.

You may also look at package dpkt https://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Hi, I tried struct.unpack with format "2B2B6B6B6B2B6B" where B is unsigned char ,2 represents 2 of B as per the ieee80211_hdr struct,is this correct format of unpacking from c struct to python?. This is unpacking the data into binary but the data of mac is in hex. Should I try again hexify the bin data again?